# Swipe event on "complex" layout

Tags: android, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to implement the swipe gesture on a layout. Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/switcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blister_background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum=".9" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgOne"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:src="@drawable/yellow" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgTwo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:src="@drawable/yellow" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgThree"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:src="@drawable/yellow" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgFour"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:src="@drawable/yellow" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgFive"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:src="@drawable/yellow" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgSix"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:src="@drawable/yellow" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewSwitcher>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the java code, I set the `setOnTouchListener` for the `ViewSwitcher`, returning the boolean returned by the `GestureDetector`. So I override the `onFling` method and actually it works. The only problem is that it works if I'm not touching the Imageviews.

The ImageViews are listening for the `onClick` event.

So, how can I swipe on the Imageviews and still recall the code inside the `onFling` method?

I tried to set the `onTouchListener` even fot he ImageViews but they don't catch the `onCLick` event anymore.

Comment: First the `ViewSwitcher` is a "`ViewAnimator` that switches between **two views**". If you want more views you should use a `ViewFlipper`.
And the only thing that is inside that views should be the content that is swiped. If you do that, you won't have problems.

Comment: Actually I need to switch among two views. And the content (the six ImageViews) is the one I need to swipe.

Answer (score 0):

on the `ViewSwitcher` put the layouts as **wrap_content** like this:

```
<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/switcher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/blister_background" >
```